# Problemas com AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, json

Estou a usar pela primeira vez *AutoCompleteTextView* com *Json* que trás através do *google* as ruas. Corre tudo bem até ao momento em que clico na rua e recebo imaginemos que clico na rua **"Rua do StackoverFlowPortuguês"** em na minha *AutoCompleteTextView* recebo *"{ description =  Rua do StackoverFlowPortuguês } "* 
[Tutorial que segui](http://androidmapv2.blogspot.pt/2013/11/android-autocompletetextview-with.html)